# Retrieving instances from event lists in google calendar api

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm working on an application that uses a couple of google's apis. What I have is something like below. I used the alerts to see how the data was being displayed. The order of the alerts is below the snippet, assuming there were only 3 events, and each were recurring.

```
function handleAuthResult2(authResult){
    if (authResult) {
        gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
            var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                calendarId: 'primary',
                timeMin: '<%=String.format('%tFT%<tT-00:00', new Date())%>'
            });         
            request.execute(function(resp) {            
                for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {               
                    if (resp.items[i].recurrence){
                        var request2 = gapi.client.calendar.events.instances({
                              calendarId: 'primary',
                              eventId: resp.items[i].id
                        });
                        request2.execute(function(resp2){
                            alert('Recurring event original start time: ' + resp2.items[0].originalStartTime)
                        });
                    } 
                    alert('Event summary: ' + resp.items[i].summary)
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The order the alerts would show:

```
Event summary: Some summary 1
Event summary: Some summary 2
Event summary: Some summary 3
Recurring event original start time: May 5, 2013
Recurring event original start time: May 6, 2013
Recurring event original start time: May 7, 2013
```

The order of alerts I want to show:

```
Recurring event original start time: May 5, 2013
Event summary: Some summary 1
Recurring event original start time: May 6, 2013
Event summary: Some summary 2
Recurring event original start time: May 7, 2013
Event summary: Some summary 3
```

This is why I'm trying to fix this: My applications displays upcoming events from users' calendar. Since recurring events won't show the next event in the 'list' method, I'm retrieving the specific details with the 'instances' method. I was putting the details in a table and it was looking like:

```
**| Upcoming Event    | Date      |**
| Event 1           | October 3 |
| Event 2           | October 7 |
| Recurring event 1 |           | //should show October 8
| Event 3           | Ocober 11 |
| Recurring event 2 |           | //should show October 12
| Event 4 | October 15October 8October 12|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use singleEvents=true parameter in the list request to avoid the second call. This will ask the server to do the recurring event expansion for you right away.

Comment: Perfect! I did see this option before. The problem I had was it listed every single event from the time it was created to whenever it was set to end. But I all I have to do is set the timeMin and timeMax and I'm good. I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When first request is made(that is to gapi.client.calendar.events.list) as there is nothing outside the method it waits until it gets response from the server. Once it enters into the for loop, it starts executing,when control reaches to the request2.execute(function(resp2),request will be sent to gapi.client.calendar.events.instances and request method won't wait for the server response as the execute operation is asynchronus. In the first request execute method has to wait as there is no code after the request operation. But after the second request alert('Event summary: ' + resp.items[i].summary) is there to execute. Because of this reason, the output is:

Event summary: Some summary 1

Event summary: Some summary 2

Event summary: Some summary 3

Recurring event original start time: May 5, 2013

Recurring event original start time: May 6, 2013

Recurring event original start time: May 7, 2013

Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientRequest) for the documentation and [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises) for promises in Java script which helps you.

Comment: Is there a complete example of the promises or whatever is needed @SGC?